# React native deeplinking is not navigating inside stack navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, deep-linking, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator

I'm using react-native navigation 5 in my app. I'm trying to add deeplinking. I create a file for config

```
const config = {
  screens: {
    Home: 'home',
    Profile: {
      path:"starter/profile/:id",
      parse: {
        id: (id) => `${id}`
      },
    },
    Notifications: "notifications",
    Settings: "settings"
  
  },
};

const linking = {
  prefixes: ["yenir://app"],
  config,
};

export default linking;
```

In switch navigator I'm trying to navigate this stack `SwitchNavigator >  Starter > Settings`

Switch navigator

```
render() {

    const SwitchNavigator= createSwitchNavigator(
    {
   // Starter: AdjustTest,
    Starter:Teststk,
    //  Starter:TstStack,
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: LoginStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName:'Starter',
    resetOnBlur:false,
    backBehavior:null
  
  }
);
```

The stack screens I want to navigate

```
const Testst = createStackNavigator();

function Teststk() {
  return (
    <Testst.Navigator>
      <Testst.Screen name="Home" component={TestStack}  />
      <Testst.Screen name="Notifications" component={TestStack}  />
      <Testst.Screen name="Profile" component={TestStack}  />
      <Testst.Screen name="Settings" component={TestStack}  />
    </Testst.Navigator>
  )
}
```

The link url user clicks. `test://app/starter/profile/2`

I can't get inside this page. How should I change the config, the routing map. Thank you

Comment: is the prefixed correct ? yenir://

Comment: yes its correct for app

Comment: `test://app/starter/profile/2` but you use `test` instead `yenir`